# solve an integration using MapleSoft

Tags: integration, maple, calculus

I encountered some problems while trying to solve an integration equations using MapleSoft.There are 4 functions that are important. Here is my code defining the functions and trying to solve the problem:

**"T is the starting point of the problem where it's given."**

`{T := proc (t) options operator, arrow; sqrt(t)/(sqrt(t)+sqrt(1-t))^2 end proc;}`

**"Now I solved for the inverse of function T."**

`V := proc (t) options operator, arrow;([solve(t = T(y), y, useassumptions)], [0 <= t and t <= 1]) end proc;`    '

**"Only the first solution to the above is the correct inverse as we can see from the plot below."**

`sol := [allvalues(V(t))]; plot([t, T(t), op(1, sol), op(2, sol)], t = 0 .. 1, legend = [typeset("Curve: ", "t"), typeset("Curve: ", "T(t)"), typeset("Curve: ", "V(t)"), typeset("Curve: ", "V2(t)")]);`

**"Now I define the first solution as my inverse function called V1."**

`V1 := proc (t) options operator, arrow; evalf(op(1, sol)) end proc`

**"As the problem required, I have to find the derivative of V1. I call it dV."**

`dV := proc (t) options operator, arrow; diff(V1(t), t) end proc`

**"Then define a new function called F"**
`F := proc (t) options operator, arrow; -10*ln(1-t*(1-exp(-1))) end proc`

**"With V1(t), F(t), dV(t) defined, we define a new function U."**
`U := proc (t,lambda) options operator, arrow; piecewise(t <= .17215, min(IVF(V1(t)), max(0, 12-(1/4)/(lambda^2*dV(t)^2))), .17215 <= t, min(IVF(V1(t)), max(0, 12-(1/4)*.7865291304*lambda^-2))) end proc;`

**"Next I will be trying to find the value of lambda, such that the"**
`solve(int(U(t,lambda)*dV(t),t=0..1)= R,lambda)`

**"where the R will be a real number, let's say 2.93 for now."**

I think the code works fine all the way till the last step where I had to solve the integration. I couldn't figure out why.
I was trying to progress further, solving the U, i.e U(t) will be 0 if t<=0.17215 and 12-(1/4)/(lambda^2*dV(t)^2)<=0 or t>=0.17215 and 12-(1/4)*0.7865291304*lambda^-2<=0 and so on so forth. But had problem solving the inequality. For example, solve(12-1/4*lambda^-2*dV(t)^-2<=0,t). The programme runs indefinitely. 
Appreciate your input!

Comment: OK, wow. That is one hard to read question. Please format it better. If the code can be separated from the comments, please do so.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I have been using StackOverflow for short time. Does this look better?

Comment: Your call to `int` is likely to fail (return unevaluated). It looks like you're just trying to find the floating-point value of `t` which "solves" the last step. If so you should try floating-point numeric integration and rootfinding instead of exact integration and solving.  Ie. Use inert `Int` instead of active `int`, else the rootfinder will run amok needlessly re-failing the exact integration for each value tried for `t`. I can't show you details because you left out defn of `IVF`.

Comment: Thank you so much acer. I think I kind of get what you meant. After using Int, I should use eval to find the evaluation? Also, my bad, IVF is actually the V(t) I defined above. I will change that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by `IVF(V1(t))` you really meant `F(V(t))` .

It seemed to me that computation of your `dV(t)` (and perhaps `V(t)` sometimes) for very small `t` might exhibit some numerical difficulty.

And I was worried that using a narrower range of integration like, say, `t=1.0e-2 .. 1.0`, might mess with some significant contribution to the integral from that portion.

So below I've constructed `V` and `dV` so that they raised `Digits` (only) for greater working precision on (only) their own body of calculations.

And I've switched it from symbolic integration to numeric/float integration. And I've added the `epsilon` option for that, in case you need to control the accuracy tolerance more finely.

Some of these details help with the speed issues you mentioned above. And some of those details slow the computation down a bit, while perhaps giving a greater sense of robustness of it.

The plotting command calls below are just there for illustration. Comment them out if you please.

I used Maple 2018.0 for these. If you have difficulties then please report your particular version used.

```
restart;

T:=sqrt(x)/(sqrt(x)+sqrt(1-x))^2:

Vexpr:=solve(t=T,x,explicit)[1]:
Vexpr:=simplify(combine(Vexpr)) assuming t>0, t<1:
```

The procedure for computing `V` is constructed next. It's constructed in this subtle way for two reasons:

1) It internally raises working precision `Digits` to avoid round-off error.

2) It creates (and throws away) an empty list `[]`. The effect of this is that it will *not* run under fast hardware-precision `evalhf` mode. This is key later on, during the numeric integration.

```
V:=subs(__dummy=Vexpr,
    proc(t)
    if not type(t,numeric) then
         return 'procname'(t);
       end if;
       [];
       Digits:=100;
       evalf(__dummy);
    end proc):

V(0.25);

   0.2037579200498004992002294012453548811286405373\
     653346413644953624868320875151070347969077227713469370

V(1e-9);

   1.0000000040000000119998606410199120814521886485524\
                                                          -18
     22617659574502917213370846924673012122642160567565 10
```

Let's plot `T` and `V`,

```
plot([T, V(x)], x=0..1);
```

[image]

Now let's create a procedure for the derivative of `V`, using the same technique so that it too raises `Digits` (only internal to itself) and will not run under `evalhf`.

```
dV:=subs(__dummy=diff(Vexpr,t),
     proc(t)
       if not type(t,numeric) then
         return 'procname'(t);
       end if;
       [];
       Digits:=100;
       evalf(__dummy);
     end proc):
```

Note that calling `dV(t)` for unknown symbol `t` makes it return unevaluated. This is convenient later on.

```
dV(t);

                         dV(t)

dV(0.25);

    2.44017580084567947538393626436824494366329948208270464559139762\
       2347525580165201957710520046760103982

dV(1e-15);

    -5.1961525404198771358909147606209930290335590838862019038834313\
       73611362758951860627325613490378754702

evalhf(dV(1e-15)); # I want this to error-out.

    Error, unable to evaluate expression to hardware floats: []
```

This is your `F`.

```
F:=t->-10*ln(1-t*(1-exp(-1))):
```

Now create the procedure `U`. This too returns unevaluated when either of its argument is not an actual number. Note that `lambda` is its second parameter.

```
U:=proc(t,lambda)
     if not ( type(t,numeric) and
              type(lambda,numeric) ) then
         return 'procname'(args);
     end if;
     piecewise(t <= .17215,
           min(F(V(t)), max(0, 12-(1/4)/(lambda^2*dV(t)^2))),
           t >= .17215,
           min(F(V(t)), max(0, 12-(1/4)*.7865291304*lambda^(-2))));
end proc:
```

Let's try a particular value of `t=0.2` and `lambda=2.5`.

```
evalf(U(0.2, 2.5));

                 .6774805135
```

Let's plot it. This takes a little while. Note that it doesn't seem to blow up for small `t`.

```
plot3d([Re,Im](U(t,lambda)),
       t=0.0001 .. 1.0, lambda=-2.0 .. 2.0,
       color=[blue,red]);
```

[image]

Let's also plot `dV`. This takes a while, since `dV` raises `Digits`. Note that it appears accurate (not blowing up) for small `t`.

```
plot(dV, 0.0 .. 1.0, color=[blue,red], view=-1..4);
```

[image]

Now let's construct a procedure `H` which computes the integral numerically.

Note that `lambda` is it's first parameter, which it passes as the second argument to `U`. This relates to your followup Comment.

The second parameter of `H` is passed to `evalf(Int(...))` to specify its accuracy tolerance.

Note that the range of integration is 0.001 to 1.0 (for `t`). You can try a lower end-point closer to 0.0 but it will take even longer for compute (and may not succeed).

There is a complicated interplay between the lower end-point of numeric integration, and accuracy tolerance `eps`, and the numeric behavior for `U` and `V` and `dV` for very small `t`.

(The working precision `Digits` is set to 15 inside `H`. That's just to allow the method `_d01ajc` to be used. It's still the case that `V` and `dV` will raise working precision for their own computations, at each numeric invocation of the integrand. Also, I'm using `unapply` and a forced choice of numeric integration method as a tricky way to prevent `evalf(Int(...))` from wasting a lot of time poking at the integrand to find singularities. You don't need to completely understand all these details. I'm just explaining that I had reasons for this complicated set-up.)

```
H:=proc(lambda,eps)
     local res,t;
     Digits:=15;
     res:=evalf(Int(unapply(U(t,lambda)*dV(t),t),
                    1e-3..1,
                    epsilon=eps, method=_d01ajc) - R);
     if type(res,numeric) then
       res;
     else
       Float(undefined);
     end if;
end proc:
```

Let's try calling `H` for a specific `R`.  Note that it's not fast.

```
R:=2.93;

                       R := 2.93

H(0.1,1e-3);

                         -2.93

H(0.2,1e-5);

                    0.97247264305333
```

Let's plot `H` for a fixed integration tolerance. This takes quite a while.

[edited] I originally plotted `t->H(t,1e-3)` here. But your followup Comment showed a misunderstanding in the purpose of the first parameter of that operator. The `t` in `t->H(t,1e-3)` is just a dummy name and DOES NOT relate to the `t` parameter of `V` and `dV`, and the second parameter of `U`, and the integration varaible. What matters is that this dummy is passed as the first argument to `H`, which in turn passes it as the second argument to `U`, which is used for `lambda`. Since there was confusion earlier, I'll use the dummy name `LAMBDA` now.

```
plot(LAMBDA->H(LAMBDA,1e-3), 0.13 .. 0.17 , adaptive=false, numpoints=15);
```

[image]

Now let's try and find the value of that root (intercept).

[edited] Here too I was earlier using the dummy name `t` for the first argument of `H`. It's just a dummy name and does not relate to the `t` parameter of `V` and `dV`, and the second parameter of `U`, and the variable of integration. So I'll change it below to `LAMBDA` to lessen confusion.

This is not fast. I'm minimizing the absolute value because numeric accuracy issues make this problematic for numeric root-finder `fsolve`.

```
Osol:=Optimization:-Minimize('abs(H(LAMBDA,1e-3))', LAMBDA=0.15..0.17);

             [                   -8                              ]
     Osol := [1.43561000000000 10  , [LAMBDA = 0.157846355888300]]
```

We can pick off the numeric value of lambda (which "solved" the integration).

```
rhs(Osol[2,1]);

                   0.157846355888300
```

If we call `H` using this value then we'll get a residual (similar to the first entry in `Osol`, but without absolute value being taken).

```
H(rhs(Osol[2,1]), 1e-3);

                                 -8
                     -1.435610 10
```

Now you have the tools to try and obtain the root more accurately. To do so you may experiment with:

1. tighter (smaller) `eps` the tolerance of numeric integration.
2. A lower end-point of the integration closer to 0.0
3. Even higher `Digits` forced within the procedures `V` and `dV`.

That will require patience, since the computations take a while, and since the numeric integration can fail (taking forever) when those three aspects are not working properly together.

I've I edit the body of procedure `H` and change the integration range to instead be `1e-4 .. 1.0` then I get the following result (specifying `1e-5` for `eps` in the call to `H`).

```
Osol:=Optimization:-Minimize('abs(H(LAMBDA,1e-5))', LAMBDA=0.15..0.17);

             [                   -7                              ]
     Osol := [1.31500690000000 10  , [LAMBDA = 0.157842787382700]]
```

So it's plausible that this approximate root lambda is accurate to perhaps 4 or 5 decimal places.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Acer, thank you so much!! I understand your approach now. Instead of using int(expr,a..b), I will use the method of taking limit of epislon going to 0 (like how we define an integral) to solve the problem. I just want to clarify that, my task is to find the value of lambda, given the integral is R, integrating from 0 to 1. So the ts' are set (0,1). So would I use solve(Osol=o,lambda)?

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand your last Comment.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not clear enough. So R is a real number, which is given. Now I need to find the value of lambda so that the integral of q(t)*dV(t)dt integrated from t =0 to 1 is equal to R. In your solution, you were trying to find the value for t (the boundary of the integral).

Comment: You've confused the dummy name `t` I used in a couple of places (eg. the objective function in the call to `Minimize`) with the parameter `t` of `V` and `dV` and the variable of integration. In fact that dummy name gets passed as the first argument to `H`, which is then passed as the second argument to `U`, and which is used as the "lambda". I've edited the Answer to use a less confusing dummy name. I've also added quite a few comments on the code and approach.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear: JW's Comment above is incorrect. My code -- both before and after I edited it and added extra commentary -- does exactly what was asked. That is, it finds the lambda which makes the Integral (in t, from essentually 0 to 1) equal to R. My code never did anything like finding the t boundary of integration, as JW claimed it did.

Comment: Hi Acer! Thank you so much for your solution. Recently, I've been playing around with the code. I discovered that when I set the value for R being smaller than a certain number (around 0.96). The last step where we minimize the abs(H(t,1e-3),t=0.1..0.2) doesn't seem to work. The minimized value being the value for R instead of approaching zero. Is it because there's no value for lambda that could make the H close to 0?